# Google Document AI create labeling instruction

Tags: cloud-document-ai

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/label-documents#labeling
For google Document AI, what is a labeling instruction exactly? Is it a pdf where every label are annotated using a box? If so do I just create such a pdf manually?

I also have tried importing a document object which i think is supposed to be a json, but I can't. It will be really appreciated if I can know what is the common best practice for labelling.

Answer (score 0):

From a first glance, it seems just like a general guideline / "best practices" for those that plan to use the console to annotate future documents within your project. When training the processor, it's best that you are consistent with what you do (whether for a field like `AmountDue` you include the `$` or not, etc). They include many examples of some labeling instructions, here's a link to one of them that's included on the page you linked: https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-samples-data/documentai/labeling-instructions/pretrained-1040-v2.0-2022-08-24.pdf.